# How can we check in Jenkins home directory to Github?

Tags: github, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-job-dsl

We want to check in the Jenkins home directory into Github, certainly ignoring some files/folders. As we want to have everything defined by code, we try to achieve this using Job DSL & Pipeline DSL (not writing the pipeline script inside Jenkins GUI but having it read from a workspace file - see below).

My problem right now is that, being not very proficient in both DSL's yet, I don't know how to force git to do an initial clone of the remote repo (and later push) *inside* the home directory - which is a parent directory of the job's directory.

I tried this pipeline:

```
    node('master') {
        dir('../..') {
            scm {
                git {
                    remote {
                        github('company/repo', 'https')
                        credentials('xyz')
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

The job itself is defined like this:

```
pipelineJob('backup') {
    definition {
        cps {
            script(readFileFromWorkspace('pipelines/backup.groovy'))
            sandbox(true)
        }
    }
}
```

The job fails with this error message:

```
ERROR: ‘checkout scm’ is only available when using “Multibranch Pipeline” or “Pipeline script from SCM”
```

So I guess the above used 'pipelineJob(backup)' does not fit. Should I change this, and if, how, or should I take another approach?

Another shot at this was trying to rewrite the pipeline like this:

```
        node {
            dir('../..') {
                git url: 'https://github.com/company/repo.git'
            }
        }
```

But then it won't work because credentials are missing...

Comment: I finally gave up on automatic upload via git. Though I achieved setting it all up in a Job (DSL) description, without an extra pipeline, a stable process was not possible as the git commands sometimes asked for human intervention. For example, the head became regularly detached.

So we are now archiving Jenkins home directory to a zip file and then uploading it to S3.